# PHP is corrupting files on echo

Tags: php, curl, download, corrupt

I'm using curl to get some images and other files from other sites. 
The problem is that if I write the content fetched to a file, and just do a redirect to the file downloaded the image is perfect.

But, if I just echo the content, preceded by the `Content-type: image/jpeg` header the image is always corrupted. I have checked and compared the two files and it seems like the echo adds white space to the beginning of the file which is probably what is corrupting the image. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using `trim()` on the what's fetched from the file before outputting it?

Comment: If you add some actual code then people may be able to help you..

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your opening `<?php` tag is at the very start of the file, and that you `exit` immediately after the echo.

Comment: I'm not exiting immdiately after the echo. I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you sent the `Content-type: image/jpeg` with PHP's header() function before echoing? If not the PHP still assumes that you will output HTML and upon the first echo it will prefix it with the right headers for HTML. You should: call header() with the header info you wish to output BEFORE any actual output and echo the content afterward. (If you don't specially process the results then it's not a good practice to keep it in memory --- see PHP's passthru() and friends!)